# Fastest way to fetch complex data with many-to-many relationships?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, dto

Running `SQL Server 2014`. I have multiple tables with many-to-many relationships with other tables. Many times, I need to fetch N rows from table `A`, also showing items table `B` and `C`. I want to do this as efficiently as possible.

**What is the most efficient way of doing this?** Some ideas below.

---

*Note: The client and server are not necessarily on the same network.*

### **The naive approach**

The naive approach looks something like this:

- Client asks server for N rows from table `A` and de-serializes them.
- For each item from `A`, the client then asks the server for its associated items in `B`.
- For each item from `A`, the client then asks the server for its associated items in `C`.

This leads to a crazy amount of database round trips, causing severe performance problems when on a slow network (i.e. `WAN`). It's simply not an option.

### The XML approach

By letting `SQL Server` generate `XML`, we can deliver structured data to the client.

- Client asks server for an `XML` for N rows from table `A`, where each row contains items from `B` and `C`. The XML is then de-serialized to a ready-to-use object in `C#`.

It could look something like this:

```
<data>
  <a_collection>
    <a>
      <id>1</id>
      <title>A Title<title>
      <b_collection>
        <b>
          <id>123</id>
          <description>B stuff here</description>
        </b>
        <b>
          <id>124</id>
          <description>Other B stuff here</description>
        </b>
      </b_collection>
      <c_collection />
    </a>
  </a_collection>
</data>
```

I like this approach, but it's slow. As the number of rows increases, and the relationships become more complex, the **`XML` serialization on `SQL Server` becomes slow**. Are there ways to somehow improve the `XML` serialization in terms of CPU and RAM usage?

### The JSON approach

When `SQL Server 2016` is released, we will have the option to use `JSON` instead of `XML`. Maybe the `XML` approach above can then be converted to `JSON` and possibly benefit from a faster serializer? But how would you de-serialize the objects when you can no longer benefit from `System.Xml.Serialization`?

### The WCF approach

Creating an extra layer between the client and the database server seems like a good idea. How would such a solution compare to i.e. the `XML` approach?

### Other approach?

There ought to be other efficient ways of delivering structured data from an `SQL Server` to a client.

Comment: My answer was to "thin" obviously. I did some edits to put this on better arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation the XML approach was mine...

EDIT: I think it's best to think of four different issues:

1. fetching data (joins, filter, aggregations)
2. preparing your data (XML, JSON, other)
3. transmitting your data (byte size)
4. de-serializing in your application

ad 1) *Performance-Impact: ~85%*

Let the SQL Server do the hard job... Assuming a well designed structure and the fitting indices there won't be a faster way  to get your data. SQL Server has huge abilities to find the "most bestest" way to join to filter and to aggregate your data in exactly the way you need it. There won't be a better way. If your data has a very big amount of pre-loadable not changing tables you might speed things up with a "load-on-start".

I'd use parameterized table valued **inline (!!!)** UDFs. They are best in maintenance and performance and you can split your needs in modular pieces easily.

ad 2) *Performance-Impact: ~4%*

I'd do an extra `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()` on the UDFs from 1). With `FOR XML PATH` you have full control on the out given XML. You can change this easily to a JSON approach later. You might think of your own format (kind of csv?) but I wouldn't...

ad 3) *Performance-Impact: ~1%*

The data transfered will be close to the smallest possible. An own format would be the smallest, but JSON is small enough and XML is not that much bigger... I don't think, that you really have to bother about byte-size to much... XML is most powerfull (adding meta data via attributs).

ad 4) *Performance-Impact: ~10%*

Within C# you have great support to get the data into queryable structure. One very plain approach is the [DataSet.ReadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Another plain approach is [XmlDocument.LoadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

With a pe-defined structure you can de-serialize your XML directly into a user defined class...

**Facit**

AFAIC is the only relevant point the No 1). The data transfered is quite the same in any case, some bytes overhead more or less... Even without explicit serialization there will be some implicit serialization and de-serialization in order to send your data to the application. The performance differences won't really matter...

Last but not least this approach was easy to integrate into a service oriented architecture...

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! +1 for "load-on-start" and TVFs!